# First route to put message on queue and second to read message

Tags: jms, apache-camel

I have problem with Camel and JMS.

My routes are very simple:

```
  @Override
    protected RouteBuilder[] createRouteBuilders() throws Exception {
        createJmsComponent();

        RouteBuilder route1 = new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:startpoint")
                .log("TO JMS: ${body}")
                .to("jms://queue:QUEUE.NAME.OUT?replyTo=QUEUE.NAME.IN&replyToType=Exclusive")
                ;
            }
        };

        RouteBuilder route2 = new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("jms://queue:QUEUE.NAME.IN?receiveTimeout=10000")
                .log("FROM JMS: ${body}")
                ;
            }
        };
        return new RouteBuilder[]{route1, route2};
    }
```

And in logs I have what I need:

```
2012-07-04 16:28:10,443 INFO  route1 - TO JMS: message
2012-07-04 16:28:13,477 INFO  route2 - FROM JMS: message
```

But the problem is that I've got Exception:

```
2012-07-04 16:28:33,960 ERROR o.a.c.p.DefaultErrorHandler                        - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-PLWROW912268-4634-1341412084839-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-PLWROW912268-4634-1341412084839-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: ID-PLWROW912268-4634-1341412084839-0-3 not received. Exchange[Message: message]
org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 20000 millis due reply message with correlationID: ID-PLWROW912268-4634-1341412084839-0-3 not received. Exchange[Message: message]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.processReply(ReplyManagerSupport.java:126) ~[camel-jms-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.onTimeout(TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.java:61) [camel-jms-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap.onEviction(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:53) [camel-jms-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap.onEviction(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:30) [camel-jms-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.purge(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:203) [camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at org.apache.camel.support.DefaultTimeoutMap.run(DefaultTimeoutMap.java:159) [camel-core-2.9.2.jar:2.9.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [na:1.6.0_23]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317) [na:1.6.0_23]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150) [na:1.6.0_23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [na:1.6.0_23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.6.0_23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204) [na:1.6.0_23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [na:1.6.0_23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [na:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_23]
```

If I understand correctly, now I have two routes which waiting for response. Route2 read the response from Queue, route1 doesn't got response(because was readed by route2) and this is reason why I got Exception.

So what I need to do to get this scenario:

```
route1 - only send message to JMS and not waiting for response. 
route2 - only read message from JMS.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solutions is to use inOnly pattern and preserveMessageQos=true flag.

```
.inOnly("jms://queue:QUEUE.NAME.OUT" +
                            "?replyTo=QUEUE.NAME.IN" +
                            "&replyToType=Shared" +
                            "&preserveMessageQos=true")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want route1 to send a message to a queue that route2 is listening on, then don't use replyTo or separate queues...just do this.

```
from("direct:startpoint").log("TO JMS: ${body}").to("jms://queue:QUEUE.NAME.IN");

from("jms://queue:QUEUE.NAME.IN").log("FROM JMS: ${body}");
```

Comment: If I don't use replyTo then I got Exception:
org.apache.camel.RuntimeExchangeException: Failed to resolve replyTo destination on the exchange: Exchange[Message: message]